# Ошибка сервера 500

Tags: apache, php

При выполнии скрипта выдает ошибку сервера:

> Ошибка HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error): Непредвиденная ситуация была обнаружена в то время как сервер пытался выполнить запрос.

В чем проблема?

Если есть необходимость, то выложу скрипт. В нем никакого обращения к базе нет.
Сервер стоит `lamp-server`

```
<?php
  $content="";
  ob_start();
  require_once "conf.php";
  $erro=false;
  if (!isset($_POST['save'])){
    $_POST['nazv']="";
    $_POST['opis']="";
    $_POST['cat']="";
  }
  else {
    $nazv=$_POST['nazv'];
    $opis=$_POST['opis'];
    $cat=$_POST['cat'];
    if (($nazv ==="") || ($opis==="") || ($cat===""){
      $erro=true;
      echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert (\"Одно из полей не заполнено\"); </script>";
      echo ("Одно из полей не заполнено");
    }
    if ($_FILES['myfile']['type']!="image/jpeg") {
      $erro=true;
      echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert (\"Не указан файл\"); </script>";
    }
  }
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Введите название: <br>
  <input type="text" name="nazv"><br>
  Введите описание: <br>
  <input type="text" name="opis"><br>
  Выберите категорию:<br>
  <input type ="text" name="cat"><br>
  <INPUT NAME=myfile TYPE=file><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="save">
  <input type="submit" name="otmena">
</form>

<?php
  $content=ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: Сразу два вопроса: работает ли ПХП вообще? Если написать совсем примитивный скрипт, например <?php phpinfo() ?> - он отработает.
Вопрос второй - что пишет апач в своём логе?

Comment: php работает. А вот log апача не могу найти что то (((((

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу, это l(linux)amp или все же w(windows)amp? Если линуксовый, тогда что есть в конфиге `httpd.conf` для директив `ErrorLog` и `LogLevel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в другом была.... Спасибо Dmitri Kadykov за намек посмотреть логи.

Comment: @new_russian_man Если вы нашли ответ сами, выложите его. Думаю, всем будет интересно его узнать.

Answer (score 1):

Если этот скрипт скопирован правильно, то вроде скобки не хватает:

```
if (($nazv ==="") || ($opis==="") || ($cat==="")
```

Ошибку 500 это вроде вызвать не должно, но всё же...

Comment: И это тоже. Скоптровал неверно. Но спасибо за наблюдательность...